# Flutter - how to cancel a SSE Stream

Tags: flutter, server-sent-events

Hey I cant figure out how to cancel an SSE Stream in my flutter app.

I am using this package to use SSE in my app: https://pub.dev/packages/sse_channel

I feel like it has a major lack in the documentation.

The SSE works fine just don't know how to stop it with a function.

Im using this to start the SSE

```
channel = SseChannel.connect(Uri.parse(dotenv.env['BASE_URL'] + '/sse/rn-updates'));
```

and

```
channel.stream.listen((message) { code... and some other stuff }
```

that part works but I don't know how to close it.

Tried stuff like this

```
static void cancelStream() {
if (channel != null)
channel.sink.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a global var in your class

```
StreamSubscription? stream;
```

and assign it to this variable

```
stream = channel.stream.listen((message) { code... and some other stuff }
```

and you can use this code to cancel stream

```
stream?.cancel();
```

Comment: Hey, seems to be working but i get this "error" printed after its close. [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close. Is this normal or?

Comment: @MarkoŽilić when you call stream?.cancel(); ?

Comment: yeah it gets printed every time some info would come to the stream after i Call on the stream.cancel().

Comment: I think its because I closed the stream, not the actual SSechannel.